# Laravel 10: Request contains original row data and not form data

Tags: laravel

I'm seeing something weird in Laravel 10, where it's passing the original row data into the first parameter of each method in a controller.

In this instance, `$request` is the original object I've edited instead of the object from the form.

Vue, using Inertia.js, and Ziggy:

```
<script setup>

import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput.vue';
import { Head, Link, useForm, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

defineProps({
    organisation: {
        type: Object,
    },
});

const organisation = usePage().props.organisation;

const form = useForm({
    name: organisation.name,
    description: organisation.description,
    website: organisation.website,
    address: organisation.address,
    telephone: organisation.telephone,
    email: organisation.email,
});

</script>

<template>

    <form @submit.prevent="form.patch(route('organisation.update', organisation.id))" class="mt-6 space-y-6">
        <div>
            <InputLabel for="name" value="Name" />
            <TextInput
                id="name"
                type="text"
                class="mt-1 block w-full"
                v-model="organisation.name"
                required
                autofocus
                autocomplete="name" />
            <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.name" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
            <PrimaryButton :disabled="form.processing">Save</PrimaryButton>

            <Transition enter-from-class="opacity-0" leave-to-class="opacity-0" class="transition ease-in-out">
                <p v-if="form.recentlySuccessful" class="text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Saved.</p>
            </Transition>
        </div>
    </form>

</template>
```

Model:

```
class Organisation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'website',
        'address',
        'telephone',
        'email',
    ];

    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

Router:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/organisation', [OrganisationController::class, 'index'])->name('organisation.index');
    Route::get('/organisation/edit/{id}', [OrganisationController::class, 'edit'])->name('organisation.edit')->whereUuid('id');
    Route::patch('/organisation/update/{id}', [OrganisationController::class, 'update'])->name('organisation.update');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'website' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'telephone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    $organisation = Organisation::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    $organisation->name = $request->get('name');
    $organisation->description = $request->get('description');
    $organisation->website = $request->get('website');
    $organisation->address = $request->get('address');
    $organisation->telephone = $request->get('telephone');
    $organisation->email = $request->get('email');
    $organisation->save();
}
```

So the `save()` is working, because I've swapped out a few of the `get()` methods for "ABC" and so on.

When I run `dd($request->all());` I see the original row data and not what I'm passing in via the form. I've removed the form as a possible problem with a few similar changes to that, too.

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: issue not clear to me atleast !

Comment: Your question statement is very unclear and ambiguous. Please state clearly also make sure your form action attribute muust have this function url.

Comment: Show how are you sending the data from your form. The issue should be there.

Comment: I've not seen Laravel do something like this before, so it's been a bit difficult figuring  out how best to explain what's going wrong. I've added the code from Vue.

Answer (score 0):

First, I had to use FormData:

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('name', form.name || '')
formData.append('description', form.description || '')
formData.append('website', form.website || '')
formData.append('address', form.address || '')
formData.append('telephone', form.telephone || '')
formData.append('email', form.email || '')
```

Then, make a change to the form:

```
form.patch(route('organisation.update', organisation.id), formData)
```

And last, swap 'organisation' for 'form' in `v-model`.